# Change Backgroundcolor of TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.5, ribbon

I'm using the .NET 4.5 WPF Ribbon and want to change the background color of one particular RibbonTab, in all situations (independent of whether it is selected, hovered over, or not - don't ask why). Usually I'd look at the code of the template in Blend but trying to copy the style fails with the error "could not copy template".

So far I have the following:

```
<RibbonTab.HeaderStyle>
    <Style TargetType="RibbonTabHeader" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type RibbonTabHeader}}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</RibbonTab.HeaderStyle>
```

The problem is that I cannot seem to find out a way on how to change the color when the tab control is selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't comment, because I don't have enough reputation yet.

The `RibbonTabHeader` has the following properties:

- `CheckedBackground` - Gets or sets the brush that is used to draw the
  background of the control when it is in the Checked state.
- `FocusedBackground` - Gets or sets the brush that is used to draw the
  background of the control when it has focus.
- `MouseOverBackground` - Gets or sets the brush that is used to draw
  the background of the control when the mouse is over it.
- `Background` - Gets or sets a brush that describes the background of
  a control. (Inherited from Control.)

Have you tried setting the `MouseOverBackground` to `Yellow`,
the `CheckedBackground` to the color you would like to use when it's selected and the `Background` for the "not selected, not hovering" state.

Answer (score 1):

using [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) I figured out that it is the `CheckedBackground` that you need to change for your `RibbonTab`. The reason being that in the template there is a border that triggers its background when its parent IsSelected changes. This color is bound to `CheckedBackground` and `Background` respectively.
I was able to create a working example with this code:

```
<RibbonTab>
    <RibbonTab.Header>
        <RibbonTabHeader Content="TabName here"
                         CheckedBackground="Red"
                         Background="Red" />
    </RibbonTab.Header>
</RibbonTab>
```

This stays red when selected and unselected.